# What does $R^I$ stand for?

Tags: general-topology

In section 30 of Munkres, one exercise states that "Give $R^I$ the uniform metric, where $I=[0,1]$".

I guess it's not about powers or something, it's some conventional notation because I've never faced it before in Munkres. What does $R^I$ stand for?

Comment: Assuming that $R=\mathbb R$, my bet would be: Set of functions $I\to \mathbb R$ with supremum-norm (so that sequences converge w.r.t the norm iff they converge uniformly). However, without additional assumptions (e.g. continuity) this fails to be a norm ... Fortunately, we only need a *metric*. not a norm, so one mighttry something like $d(f,g)=\min\{1,\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)-g(x)\}$.

Comment: @Hagen: The exercise is poorly stated. However, it turns out that it actually deals only with $C(I,\Bbb R)$, so $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)-g(x)|$ is doubtless intended.